# Four Isosceles Trapezoids

Tags: geometry, puzzle

> Suppose we have four isosceles triangles with the same area, which must some whole number less than $29$. Denote the the lower base and upper base of the $i$-th triangle with $y_i$ and $x_i$, respectively. Furthermore, suppose that the angle between the side of length yi and the adjacent sides is $45^\circ$. What will the area $A$ lengths $x_i$ and $y_i$ be?

Because the angle is $45^\circ$, the leg of the triangle and the height of the isosceles trapezoid must be equal; that is, $\displaystyle h= \frac{y_i−x_i}{2}$. Therefore, the area is given by

$\displaystyle A= \frac{y_i+x_i}{2} h$

$\displaystyle A = \frac{y_i+x_i}{2} \frac{y_i−x_i}{2}$

This is where I was not certain as to how to proceed.

---

I was advised to look at all of the integers between $1$ and $29$, find the one that could that had four factorizations, and then determine the dimensions from such information.

I found that this integer was $24$. So, for instance, the first isosceles trapezoid dimensions could be found as such:

$24=2⋅12$

Therefore, we can set up the equations

$\displaystyle \frac{y_1+x_1}{2}=12$

and

$\displaystyle \frac{y_1−x_1}{2}=2$

---

I don't quite understand this, however. Why can I write $\displaystyle 12⋅2=\frac{y_1+x_1}{2}⋅\frac{y_1−x_1}{2}$, and have this imply $\displaystyle
\frac{y_1+x_1}{2}=12$ and $\displaystyle \frac{y_1−x_1}{2}=2$?

Also, the notion of parity is to somehow factor into this problem.

How can I see this things arise naturally? I feel as though not enough justification has been provided. If someone could go through the steps with me, showing me how one idea naturally leads to next, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I the fisrst paragraph you mean "trapezoids" not "triangles" twice

Answer (score 1):

Once you get to $\displaystyle A = \frac{y_i+x_i}{2} \frac{y_i−x_i}{2}$ you are expected to argue that $\displaystyle \frac{y_i+x_i}{2} $ and $\displaystyle \frac{y_i−x_i}{2}$ must both be integers. If one is not an integer, it is a half integer and so is the other, so the product cannot be an integer.  Then, as you say, you can look at the various factorizations of $24$.  This is what you want to see how it arises naturally-it is quite common.  Each factorization (or each factorization subject to some condition) corresponds to one of the $i$s in your list.  That is why you can use $24=12 \cdot 2$ to give $\frac {y_1+x_1}2=12, \frac {y_1-x_1}2=2,y_1=14,x_1=10$-the other factorizations will give the other possibilities, like $24=6 \cdot 4$ gives $\frac {y_2+x_2}2=6, \frac {y_2-x_2}2=4,y_2=10,x_2=2$ and so on.  Parity comes in because $x_i,y_i$ must be both even or both odd to make the factors integral.

Comment: I do not understand why I have to argue that $\frac{y+x}{x}$ and $\frac{y-x}{2}$ must be integers. I want them to be integers, so I compel them to be integers; and for each fraction to evaluate to an integer, the numerator must be some multiple of $2$. Is this the sort of proof you had in mind? If not, I do not see how it is possible to prove that they must be integers.

Comment: You need that to use the factorizations.  If they didn't have to be integers, you could have them be $6\sqrt 2$ and $2 \sqrt 2$, for example.  That makes a trapezoid of area $24$, but then $x_i,y_i$ are not integers.

Comment: Oh, wait! When I wrote the problem statement, I forgot to write that $x$ and $y$ are assumed to be positive integers. How does that change things? Could I immediately infer that $\displaystyle A = \frac{y+x}{2} \cdot \frac{y-x}{2}$ means that $A$ has to be factored into two positive integers?

Comment: Yes, because they are then either both integers or both half integers.  If they are half integers, A will not be an integer.